# How to Build a React Application with Multiple HTML Files?

Tags: html, reactjs

The project I am currently working on is the first React project i've worked on. I have a lot of experince with backend and some with front end. The backend I have already written strongly relies on diffrent html pages / end point urls. (There are other Stackoverflow posts about a simular topic but I would rather not have to eject my program.

My current render:

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./styles.css";

import Login from "./Pages/Login"
import Reset from './Pages/Reset';

ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><Login /></StrictMode>, document.getElementById('login'));
ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><Reset /></StrictMode>, document.getElementById('reset'));
```

Then I have two html files one that has a div login and one that has div reset but only the index.html or login one works when i move the built files to the backend.
(I use react because it makes it a lot easier to make clean webpages)

I haven't really tried very much, I have looked into other ways but all the tutorials / articals I have found have been very outdated.

Answer (score 1):

React is used to build, specifically, Single Page Applications (SPAs). So your attempt at building two `index.html`, i.e. two different SPAs seems strange.

Since you've decided to build two different index.html, you can do this by building each component one at a time by commenting the other `ReactDOM.render` line.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><Login /></StrictMode>, document.getElementById('login'));
// ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><Reset /></StrictMode>, document.getElementById('reset'));
```

```js
// ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><Login /></StrictMode>, document.getElementById('login'));
ReactDOM.render(<StrictMode><Reset /></StrictMode>, document.getElementById('reset'));
```

Comment: Note: If you are trying to serve different components on different routes look into `Next.js`

Comment: PS: If you are trying to build two different `index.js` (possibly more with more routes) this process of building each component separately will get more tedious and unconventional.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

Routes, Route to make Route for change between different pages:

```
 import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
 
 import Login from "./Pages/Login"
 import Reset from './Pages/Reset';

  <BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/home" element={<Login/>}/>
     <Route path="/Reset" element={<Reset/>}/>
   </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only have one HTML to setup React/JS which should have only `<div id="root"></div>` (id name should be constant with the js id). The two HTML that you have, u should rewrite them in JSX and either have them in the js file that you use here or have each of them have a js file and link them. Here is an example of how it should be.

import React from 'https://esm.sh/react@18.2.0'
import ReactDOM from 'https://esm.sh/react-dom@18.2.0'

```
const App=()=>{
  
  return(
    <div>
  <div className="login">
      <button>
        Login
      </button>
  </div>
    <div className="login">
      <button>
        Reset
      </button>
  </div>
      </div>
  )
  
      
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In React you only need a single `index.html` file.

`public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In order to make multiple URLs work in React, use a library called `react-router-dom`.

`src/index.js`

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

import Login from "./Pages/Login"
import Reset from './Pages/Reset';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/reset" element={<Reset/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

For the remaining HTML files you want as pages, you can convert to React components files like below.

`src/Pages/Login.js`

```
import React from "react";

function Login() {
  return <div>Login Page</div>;
}

export default Login;
```

`src/Pages/Reset.js`

```
import React from "react";

function Reset() {
  return <div>Reset Page</div>;
}
```

To import multiple HTML files without converting, in React, use `html-react-parser`.

`src/index.js`

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Parser from "html-react-parser";

import Login from "./Pages/Login.html";
import Reset from "./Pages/Reset.html";


ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<>{Parser(Login)}</>} />
        <Route path="/reset" element={<>{Parser(Reset)}</>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[Edit it on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-implementation-with-html-files-3hj36p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: OT said the backend has strong need for multiple htmls.

Comment: Might need `html-react-parser` for it.

Answer (score 0):

React is a SPA, which is designed to use single page application to solve multiple pages problems. When you first create a React Application, `src/index.js` and `src/APP.js` will in the project, which you can use for configuration for multiple pages.
You can use `react-router-dom` like below:

src/index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
 
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

src/APP.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route }
    from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Reset from './pages/Reset';
 
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' exact element={<Login />} />
                <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                <Route path='/reset' element={<Reset />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}
 
export default App;
```